# express - optional slash at the end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have to following route:

```
app.get("/download/:id/:name?",function(req,res){});
```

How can I make the last slash in the url optinal, if the param "name" is not given?
For example, a request "/download/abc" wouldn't match this route. It would have to be "/download/abc/". Is there way to make "/download/abc" match?

Comment: Actually, it will match. Express does this automatically. It's not super-clear from the docs, but check the regex in [req.route](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route) -- or just try it yourself!

Comment: You guy are right :) My fault... the question does not make sense xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get("/download/:id/:name?*", ...);
```

This works for `download/parameter`, but also for `download/parameter/anotherparameter/...`